# Ubuntu Dash Plugins

Tags: unity, unity-dash

[image]

How is these dash plugins used? The description says that they can let information being displayed under various headers. But when I really search it, the results wanted are not included, neither are the **headers**. I've enabled all the plugins. Can anyone explain how to use those plugins? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply type something.

But keep in mind:

- You need online results turned on for most of these
  [image]
- type on the home scope to get results, the Applications one will only show which ones are installed
- Some are disabled by default, because typing certain things in result in data being sent, in these situations you need to select them in filters

[image]

- The filters are reset on a new search, and seem to be selected dynamically based on what you search.

Some only seem to be activated by specifically searching using the name - example `manpages: htop` will search the manpages for htop, or `calc: 1+1` will show specific results:
[image]

- some are broken... facebook, flickr, yelp, don't seem to produce results...